# Determinant of triangular matrix with extra diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-complexity

If we have a triangular matrix we can calculate the determinant in $O(n)$. If we have a triangular matrix with one extra diagonal above the main diagonal, so for example:

\begin{Vmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & 0 & 0 \\
d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_4 & d_5 & 0 \\
e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4 & e_5 & e_6 \\
f_1 & f_2 & f_3 & f_4 & f_5 & f_6 
\end{Vmatrix}

where we have the extra diagonal $[a_2, b_3, c_4,...,f_6]$, is there a way to calculate the determinant faster than the standard $O(n^3)$?

Comment: It seems likely. Using elementary tow operations, can’t we subtract  $e_6/f_6$ times the sixth row from the fifth row (assuming $f_6$ is nonzero) and so on for each row? It seems to me this would not be $O(n^3)$ so would improve it.

Comment: So we would essentially multiply this matrix with an upper triangular matrix such that the result eliminates $e_6$, and so on until we have a lower triangular matrix (in $O(n^2)$ operations). Since all the operations were upper triangular matrices we have a LU decomposition and can easily get the determinant. So overall we would get $O(n^2)$. Is that correct? And is that the best we can do?

Comment: That’s what I’m suggesting yes.  I don’t know if that’s the best we can do, but it seems to me the traditional $O(n^3)$ algorithm is basically just doing that $n$ times, once for each “off diagonal”. So that makes me think $O(n^2)$ is optimal.